# How to execute some shell script before VM suspend?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, vmware, virtualization

I have created one Centos VM. And I have created some IP aliases. Once I suspend and resume the VM my IP aliases are all going down. So I just want to capture the aliases address before suspend and bring up those IP's after resume.

How to do this?

I just want a script, I don't want to use VMware tools for this..

Comment: Why don't you configure your IP aliases correctly inside ifcfg-$dev files?

Comment: I am running one project, during run time based on some user input it will create the ipaliases , due to this i havent configured inside ifcfg-$dev file.

Comment: When you say IP aliases do you mean eth0:0 or interfaces such as this?

Answer (score 0):

In CentOS one can create aliases (NIC variety - aka. clone devices) through the use of a configuration file named like so, `ifcfg-<if-name>:<alias-value>`. These files live here: `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/`.

#### Example

Create the following file, `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0:0`. Then inside the file create the following content:

```
DEVICE=eth0 
ONBOOT=yes 
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
```

You can add additional lines in here, depending on the nature of the alias/clone; lines such as:

```
NETWORK=10.0.1.0 
NETMASK=255.255.255.0 
IPADDR=10.0.1.27 
USERCTL=no
```

See the official RHEL/CentOS docs for more details, they do a good job of covering the sea of options and are easy to follow, titled: [13.2. Interface Configuration Files](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-networkscripts-interfaces.html).

#### Bringing up/down network interfaces

Once the lines have been added, you can stop/start the networking stack using this service:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/network <cmd>
```

To just bring up/down an individual NIC device:

```
$ sudo ifup <interface>
$ sudo ifdown <interface>
```

#### Example

Bring up entire networking stack:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/network start
```

Bring up individual interface:

```
$ sudo ifup eth0:0
```

#### Running custom scripts during VM state changes

If you'd like to not have to bring all your aliases up and down you can use the facility provided by VMware to create scripts that will run during one its state changes (Suspsend/Start/Stop/Resume).

Custom scripts, that are executable (`chmod +x ...`), can be placed in these directories.

- (ToolsDir)/script/resume-vm-default.d/
- (ToolsDir)/script/suspend-vm-default.d/
- etc.

The location of ToolsDir is dependent on where the software was installed on your system. You'll have to search for this location if you're not sure where it is.

Comment: I am not creating any file like ifcfg-<if-name>:<alias-value>. I am using this command to create the alias ifconfig eth0:<alias-value> <IPAddress> .

Comment: @MadhuChitloor - yes those files I've discussed are what are used to create the ifcfg eth0:<alias-value><IPAddress>.

Comment: I have large number of aliases ,so i cant create so many files.If i do as you said the to restart the network service it will take long time to come up.

Comment: I have already implemented the logic to capture the alias address and how to bring all those alias up. But i need information about where to place that script ,so that it can execute before suspend of the vm ?